# Quotient of Integral Extensions is Integral

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

If $A \subset B$ is an integral extension, then $\frac{B}{J} $ is integral over $\frac{A}{I}$ where $I=J \cap A$.

I was able to prove this theorem but I am wondering why can't be generalise it for any ideal of $A$?
So inshort I want to understand why are we taking the ideal $J \cap A$ but not some other ideal? Will it work for some other ideals? Can I generalise this?

I was looking for some counterexamples in this case.

Can I try with $I=\mathbb{Q} \subset \mathbb{Q}=A$ and $J={0} \subset \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt2)$

In this case we have $\frac{A}{I}=0$ and $\frac{B}{J}=B$ and definitely $B$ isn't integral over $0$ because there doesn't even exists any non-constant polynomial.

I would like to see some more interesting examples

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When talking about integral extension, $A/I$ need to be a subring of $B/J$, now if $I=A\cap J$, then the natural map $A/I\mapsto B/J$ is injective, but when take $J$ arbitrary ideal of $B$ and $I$ arbitrary in A, how can u see $A/I$ as subring of $B/J$?the preceding map is no longer well defined, unless $A\cap J \subset I$ and is injective iff equality holds. For example if u take $J$ to be prime, then $B/J$ is an integral domain, so any subring of it must also be integral domain.but even if both ideals are prime: $B=\mathbb{Z} [\sqrt{-5} ]$ is an integral extension of $A=\mathbb{Z}$, take $ J=< \sqrt{-5} > ,I=<2> $ both are prime ideals.